# Removing ceiling fan remote

Tags: ceiling-fan

Two ceiling fans I brought from Costco with remote has been giving me troubles within a few months of use. Every time I turn off the wall switch the lights would flicker but the fan won't operate. For the first one I hired an electrician to come by and fix the non working remote/receiver unit. He said ceiling fan remotes are have problems. Does anyone know how I can remove the remote completely from my ceiling fan. I'm afraid which wires need to be paired based on the wires I see up there. Picture attached.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a Hunter brand ceiling fan. Shortly after I replaced the wall switch that physically fell apart and caused some arcing on the line, the fan would run and then stop. The amount of time it ran before stopping grew shorter & shorter, until it just wouldn't run at all.

Assuming there is a light on the remote (transmitter) that blinks when you hit a key, there is nothing wrong with the remote. Luckily it was within the one-year warranty for electronic parts and I still had my receipt. So, when I called the manufacturer (not retailer), they sent me a new speed controller for free. It would be worth it to purchase the new controller if it is not within warranty, my would have been $50 and looks just like yours.